# Despite multiple unwrapping attempts, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase

I have been practicing a login page and the creation of an account with Firebase.  I am successfully signing up a user and saving the user in firebase.  Now I am trying to save a first and last name to the user id when they create their account.  I've tried looking at other SO answers, but still can't seem to get this to work.

I have been going through multiple tutorials, and have tried multiple unwrapping attempts, but keep running into this error.  Below is my view controller:

## View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let firstName = firstNameField.text, let lastName = lastNameField.text {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password ) { (user, error) in
                // ...

                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                //add popup later
                }


                let userId = user!.uid
                self.ref.child("users").child(userId).setValue(["firstName": firstName])
                print("User registered in Firebase with a userId of " + user!.uid)

                }
        }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?  I thought I was unwrapping the variables at the top, with my 'if let'.  I tried force unwrapping them individually, as well, but keep having the same error.  A bit lost.

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: @ColGraff It's my Firebase database reference line:   self.ref.child("users").child(userId).setValue(["firstName": firstName])

Comment: Maybe this: `let userId = user!.uid`

Comment: Break that line up and see which method call causes you trouble. Or set a break  and debug it to find out which.

Comment: Where's your "multiple unwrapping attempts" on the line causing the error?

Comment: I've tried removing the children, and tried hardcoding the first name value, but keep receiving the same error unfortunately.  I've been referencing the documentation and seem to be following everything correctly @ColGraff

Comment: remove the 'var' before 'ref' in viewDidLoad

Comment: @J.Doe  that did the trick.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `viewDidLoad()`, you call

`var ref = Database.database().reference()`

but it should be

`ref = Database.database().reference()`

Swift is treating it like a different variable that you're declaring within the scope of `viewDidLoad()`, so when you go to use `ref`, it still has no value.

Comment: God, it's so obvious now.  I owe you a beer.  Thank you!

Comment: Haha I'll hold you to it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please change your Database reference from

```
 var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

to

```
 var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
```

and then do

```
 self.child("users").child(userId).setValue(["firstName": firstName])
```

or in you viewDidLoad do

```
self.ref = Database.database().reference()
```

This error happens because you are not initialising your Database reference

This should work without any problems

```js
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let firstName = firstNameField.text, let lastName = lastNameField.text {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password ) { (user, error) in
                // ...

                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                //add popup later
                }


                let userId = user!.uid
                self.ref.child("users").child(userId).setValue(["firstName": firstName])
                print("User registered in Firebase with a userId of " + user!.uid)

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried that initially, however I receive a 'use of unresolved identifier 'Database'', if I do not include the var: ref DatabaseReference!

Comment: Thats because you didn't import
 " FirebaseDatabase"